# How to send getJson request and submit input form at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, getjson

I am trying to create an input form that both displays AJAX response and submits input. However, since submit will refresh the page, AJAX response is removed immediately after the form is submitted. How do I retain the response?

Below is my code.

```js
                    $('#inputButton').click(function () {
                        var URL = 'URLEXAMPLE';
            $.getJSON(URL, function(data){
                
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    var info = data[i].content;
                                $("#jsonInfo").append(info);
                            };
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputButton" type="submit" value="Done">
                <div id="jsonInfo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Reason for code not working:
>
> > 1.check your json was not closing proberly.
> >
> > 2.And try with apply     `document.ready`
> >
> > 3.From tag not Available in your Html page.I was added the form tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
                $('#inputButton').click(function (e) {
                    var URL = 'URLEXAMPLE';
                    $.getJSON(URL, function(data){

                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                            var info = data[i].content;
                            $("#jsonInfo").append(info);
                        };
                      })
                   console.log('Its work')
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
});
            </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
<input id="inputButton" type="submit" value="Done">
            <div id="jsonInfo"></div>
  </form>
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I tried running the code but was not able to submit the form. Is there something that I may be missing?

Comment: Codes are working good.What  is the  error get from your console.log.can you post with that?click the `F12`

Comment: I used the code and It's working beautifully! Thank you so much!

Comment: I noticed that it is not submitting the input. Sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#inputButton').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default behavior i.e. refresh page

    var URL = 'URLEXAMPLE';
    $.getJSON(URL, function(data){

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var info = data[i].content;
        $("#jsonInfo").append(info);
    };
});
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback! I tried implementing the above code but was not able to fix it.

Comment: Answer from prasad above.

Comment: appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("form").submit(function(ev){ //need slector to be form.
        ev.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behavior 
    });
```

or

```
   $('#inputButton').click(function () {
   $(this).parents('form').submit(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var URL = 'URLEXAMPLE';
                    $.getJSON(URL, function(data){

                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                            var info = data[i].content;
                            $("#jsonInfo").append(info);
                        };
                });
        });
```